# Javascript toggle function my version

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, toggle

I've found this js toggle function yesterday. It worked perfectly but today... it just doesn't work. I have my news feed and i wanted that each news is in a new container.... the first is opened by default the others are closed. It worked but today when I open a div it just closes itself again. And if I close the first div wich is opened by default it doesn't open again...

JAVASCRIPT FILE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#news').show();
$('a#sprozilec').click(function() {
    if (!$('#news').is(':visible')) {
        $('.prikaz').hide(400);
    }
    $('#news').slideToggle(400);
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#news2').hide();
     $('a#sprozilec2').click(function() {
       if (!$('#news2').is(':visible')) {
           $('.prikaz').hide(400);
      }
      $('#news2').slideToggle(400);
   });
});
```

NEWS FILE

```
 <a href="#" id="sprozilec" class="button">New official video!</a>
            <div id="news" class="prikaz">
                    </div>
  <a href="#" id="sprozilec2" class="button">Bla Bla Bla!</a>
            <div id="news2" class="prikaz">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your JS as,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#news').show();
    $('a#sprozilec').click(function()
    {
        if (!$('#news').is(':visible'))
        {
            $('.prikaz').hide(400);
        }
        $('#news').slideToggle(400);
    });

    $('#news2').hide();
    $('a#sprozilec2').click(function()
    {
        if (!$('#news2').is(':visible'))
        {
            $('.prikaz').hide(400);
        }
        $('#news2').slideToggle(400);
    });
});
```

You just need one `document.ready()`. And that will do.

Comment: But i see that here it works... so the problem is somewhere else in the code -.-

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your code in single `document.ready`, because if you create multiple document.ready, both will be executed at same time. In your case execution sequence of your code matters!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#news').show();
    $('a#sprozilec').click(function() {
        if (!$('#news').is(':visible')) {
            $('.prikaz').hide(400);
        }
        $('#news').slideToggle(400);
    });


    $('#news2').hide();
         $('a#sprozilec2').click(function() {
           if (!$('#news2').is(':visible')) {
               $('.prikaz').hide(400);
          }
          $('#news2').slideToggle(400);
    });
);
```

Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pA546/)

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work like this either. There must be somewhere else the problem... do you know if something can cause a problem to js?